# How to implement multiple filters in a http request with angular?

Tags: c#, angular

I'm currently working on an application that manages table reservations for a restaurant. It's built using C# on the backend and Angular on the frontend.

The app allows users to check for available tables based on the number of people, date, and time they input. Once these details are submitted, the application should return tables that match the inputted capacity at the specified date and time. This functionality is facilitated via an html form using Angular Material.

On the backend, the method utilizes an HTTP POST request, receiving parameters from the user. Testing this functionality using Postman returns the expected available tables. However, when triggering the same request from the frontend, the expected available tables aren't being retrieved.

Here are the snippets of the code used for this funcionality:

Backend - Controller:

```
[HttpPost("available")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Table>> GetReservationsByTable([FromQuery]int numberOfguests,[FromQuery] DateTime date, [FromQuery] TimeSpan time)
        {
            return await _tableRepo.GetAvailableTables(numberOfguests, date, time);
        }
```

Backend - Repository:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Table>> GetAvailableTables(int numberOfGuests, DateTime date, TimeSpan time)
        {

            var reservations = await _context.Reservations.Where(x => 
                (x.ReservationDate == date) &&(
                (x.ReservationTime <= time && time < (x.ReservationTime + TimeSpan.FromHours(5))  ) ||
               ( time >= (x.ReservationTime - TimeSpan.FromHours(5)) && time < x.ReservationTime)
                )) .ToListAsync();
                
            if (!reservations.Any())
            {
                return await _context.Tables.ToListAsync();
            }
            var reservedTableIds = reservations.Select(r => r.TableId);
            var availableTables = await _context.Tables
                .Where(t => !reservedTableIds.Contains(t.Id) && t.Capacity >= numberOfGuests)
                .ToListAsync();

            return availableTables;

        }
```

Frontend - Service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TablesService {
  baseUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/api/'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTables(){
    return this.http.get<Table[]>(this.baseUrl + 'table');

  }
  getAvailableTables(numberOfGuests: number, date: Date, time: Date): Observable<Table[]> {
    
    const formatedDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    const params = {
      numberOfGuests,
      date : formatedDate,
      time,
    };
    return this.http.post<Table[]>(this.baseUrl + 'table/available', params);
   
  }
}
```

Frontend - Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tables',
  templateUrl: './tables.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tables.component.scss']
})
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit {
  tables : Table[] = [];
  numberOfGuests: number = 0;
  date: Date = new Date();
  time: Date = new Date();

 constructor(private tableService : TablesService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tableService.getTables().subscribe({
      next: (response : Table[]) => this.tables = response,
      error: error => console.log(error)

    })
  }
  onUserInputChange(): void {
   
    this.getAvailableTables();
  }

  getAvailableTables(): void {
    this.tableService.getAvailableTables(this.numberOfGuests, this.date, this.time)
      .subscribe((tables) => {
        this.tables = tables;
        
      });
  }
 }
```

---

Frontend - HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-scroll shadow-0" style="background-color: #ffede7;">
 
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center mb-3">
          <a routerLink="/" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="MDB-logo" src="../../assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="Burger  house Logo"
              draggable="false" height="100" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <div class="navbar-nav align-items-center mx-auto">
  
             
                <mat-form-field >
                  <mat-label>number of guests</mat-label>
                  <input [(ngModel)]="numberOfGuests" matNativeControl required matInput placeholder="Ex. 10">
                </mat-form-field>
  
  
                <mat-icon class="ms-2 me-5">people</mat-icon>
                 <mat-form-field class="me-5">
                  <mat-label>choose a date</mat-label>
                  <input [(ngModel)]="date" matInput matNativeControl required [matDatepicker]="datePicker" [min]="date"  disabled>
                   <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #datePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
               
                <mat-form-field class="me-5">
                  <mat-label>what time</mat-label>
                  <select [(ngModel)]="time" matNativeControl required>
                    <option value="13:30:00">13:30</option>
                    <option value="14:30:00">14:30</option>
                    <option value="15:30:00">15:30</option>
                    <option value="16:30:00">16:30</option>
                  </select>
                </mat-form-field>
  
                <button mat-raised-button (click)="onUserInputChange()" color="primary">Check available tables</button>
              
            </div>
          </div>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <h2 class="text-center mb-4">Available Tables</h2>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 " >
      <div *ngFor="let table of tables" class="card " >
        <img src="{{table.pictureUrl}}" alt="{{table.tableName}}" style="height: 300px;" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Table {{ table.tableName }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Capacity: {{ table.capacity }} guests</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Navbar -->
```

How can I fix this code to achieve its functionality?

I have tried slight variations of this code regarding date and time formatting, however they did not work.

EDIT as requested:
This is what the network tab shows after the request:
[image]

The issue I'm facing is that the request is returning all tables, whereas it should only return those tables that have a capacity for more than 15 people and are available at the selected date and time. As per the example request, the expected behavior should filter and display only the relevant tables meeting these criteria.

Comment: "the expected available tables aren't being retrieved." Where exactly is the failure. Have you profiled the database to see the call coming through? What about the web service, is it processing data? What does the network tab show for the call from the front end to the web service? My bet is that the front end is getting the data, but that the interface for the deserialization of the JSON is not correct and deserialization fails.

Comment: Added more information about the failure and the network tab.

Comment: i do curious, why `param` on the `TableServices` only have explicit field name for `date`? does the parameter sent correctly in network tab?

Comment: Your backend is trying to get queryvars from POST ([FromQuery] gets from URL query string)... which is sort of odd.   You might change your call to a GET, and use HttpParams() when sending... or use a POST and use [FromBody] on backed to bind to the sent JSON.  (Just send a class/type in frontend that matches the backend model you bind to...)  As is, the URL would need to have those values... i.e. yourdomain.com/page?key=value&key2=value, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a logic error in `GetAvailableTables`. Look at the logic surrounding this line.

```
 if (!reservations.Any())
 {
     return await _context.Tables.ToListAsync();
 }
```

It appears to be saying "If no reservations...return all tables." which you report is an issue:

> The issue I'm facing is that the request is returning all tables, whereas it should only return those tables that have a capacity for more than 15 people and are available at the selected date and time.

`return await _context.Tables.ToListAsync();` will exit the call immediately and not do the subsequent logic about capacity.

I suggest you refactor that section with the following to handle the `No Reserverations` scenario properly.